# Raise error if launched output and uses result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to raise an error if the user uses return launch and result().

```
def launch(returnOutput=False):
    # Function
    if returnOutput:
       return "value"
    else:
       value = "value"

def result():
    return value
```

I want it to say like:

```
Console > print(launch(True), result())
Error: "Can't get result if launched output."
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It's possible, but pretty unusual. Why do you want this?

Comment: Just to see if its possible, and i think its kinda fun it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb so i didn't think of this:

```
def result():
    if value == None:
       # Throw error
    else:
       return value
```